# Show that the equation of the line through $(0,b)$ and $(a,0)$ can be written as $\frac{x}{a} + \frac {y}{b} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently trying this question:

> There are two coordinates $(0,b)$ and $(a,0)$. Show that the equation of a line can be written as
> $$\frac{x}{a} + \frac {y}{b} = 1$$

I understand $y=mx+c$, and basic equations, but am stuck and would love a hint please.

Comment: Please show your working so far. $y=mx+c$ is a general equation for any line. So how to we find parameters $m$ and $c$ for our specific line? What did you try?

Comment: Hint: Try to solve for $y$ in the equation. Can you define new constants so that the equation is of the form
$$
y = \text{something} \cdot x + \text{something else}
$$?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other responses, but would like to offer
an alternative approach.  Your teacher may or may not
consider this approach **valid**.

A line is completely determined by 2 distinct points. 
Therefore, your proposed equation for the line can be verified 
by simply verifying that the equation is satisfied by **both** $(a,0)$ and $(0,b).$ 
This verification is **immediate** with virtually no math.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints :**

1. Show that point $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ satisfy the given linear equation.
2. Two points determine a unique line.
3. So if two given points satisfy a given linear equation, one example being $$\frac{x}{a} + \frac {y}{b} = 1$$ then, that linear equation is the equation of unique lines passing through these points.
4. Plot these points on graph and identify where these points are located. From this infer, why we need an equation like $$\frac{x}{a} + \frac {y}{b} = 1$$ when we already have $$ y=mx+c $$

Comment: +1: I'm unsure whether my answer preceded yours.  What I do know is that your answer is *at least* as good as mine.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Equation of a line passing points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is:

$$\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac {x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

$(x_1, y_1)=(0, b)$

$(x_2, y_2)=(a, 0)$

putting values in equation we get:

$$\frac{y}{b}+\frac{x}a=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Substitute the points $(0,b)$ and $(a,0)$ into the equation of the line.

Find $m$ and $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Now you've got the equation of the line, so re-arrange the expression.